# Best way to distribute Cloud HTML5 App

Tags: html, cordova

I thought PhoneGap was a simple wrapper for HTML5, but it looks like it does in fact compile into native in some way.

I have a Cloud based, HTML5 Single Page Web application that I just want to run full screen, and distribute via an app store.

Should I just create a PhoneGap App with an InAppBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to publish an HTML5-based app in a "native" app store sucha s Google Play or Apple Store, you have 2 options:

1- Implement your own native application using a webview to show your web-based app.

2- Use some existing framework like Phonegap/Cordova even you do not use the native API. The framework will already setup everything for you to just deploy your HTML5 code.

However, if your web app is meant to be hosted remotely (i.e. not run from local files), you may encounter problems when trying to publish in the Apple Store. They have some strict rules about remote content, and about publishing apps that may not provide much more value and/or functionality than a simple web-app can.

Best.